# How is e=200sin(t+40)V equal to E=200∠40?

Tags: electrical

If we expand the first equation it goes like this: \$e = 200(\sin(\omega t)\cdot \cos(40) + \cos(\omega t)\cdot\sin(40))\$,
Which means there is still \$\sin(\omega t) + \cos(\omega t)\$ remaining in the equation.

Can somebody please elaborate on that? Or tell me which book is best to understand these type of calculations.

Comment: 1: product trig identities, 2: phasor notation

Answer (score 13):

There is no math here; the notation "amplitude∠phase" is simply shorthand for "amplitude×sin (ωt + phase)", where the frequency ω is implicit (and fixed). It's just two ways of saying exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Sinewave form:

$$e = E_M\ sin (ω t\ ±\ θ) V$$

Vector or phasor form:

$$\overrightarrow E = E_M\ ∠ ±θ \ V$$

Converting sinewaves into vectors allows complex numbers to be used to simplify calculations.

Answer (score -1):

In the unit circle

- the expression \$\cos(\omega t + \varphi)\$ is a length on the real (the horizontal) axis.
- the expression \$\sin(\omega t + \varphi)\$ is a length on the imaginary (the vertical) axis.

If you add them and multiply the sine part with *j* to account for the imaginary axis, you get an origin vector with the length 1 under the angle \$\varphi\$ to the real axis. That's equivalent to the complex math expression \$e^{j(\omega t + \varphi)}\$. What you have there as *200∠40* is the phasor writing of that expression.

**Don't drop that imaginary number marker *j*.** Leaving it out accidentally will lead to exactly that kind of confusion you are in.